# Oracle how to transpose multiple rows into aggregate column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot

I have table

```
OWNER       TABLE_NAME      COLUMN_NAME     ATTRIBUTE_ID
-------     -------         -------         -------
USER        CC_CASES        X_OIB           0
USER        CC_CASES        X_OIB_2         0
USER        CC_CASES        X_JMBG          1
USER        CC_CASES        X_JMBG_2        1
USER        CC_CASES        FIRST_NAME      2
USER        CC_CASES        FIRST_NAME_2    2
USER        CC_CASES        LAST_NAME       3
USER        CC_CASES        LAST_NAME_2     3
SUBSCRIBER  CC_CONTACT      X_OIB           0
SUBSCRIBER  CC_CONTACT      X_MB_OIB        0
SUBSCRIBER  CC_CONTACT      X_JMBG          1
SUBSCRIBER  CC_CONTACT      X_X_JMBG_2      1
SUBSCRIBER  CC_CONTACT      FIRST_NAME      2
SUBSCRIBER  CC_CONTACT      LAST_NAME       3
```

And I'm trying to transpose it to put each different ID in a different columns, and group it by table name and column name separated by comma.

I need output like:

```
OWNER       TABLE_NAME      OIB_COL         JMBG_COL            FIRST_NAME_COL              LAST_NAME_COL
-------     -------         -------         -------             -------                     -------
USER        CC_CASES        X_OIB,X_OIB_2   X_JMBG,X_JMBG_2     FIRST_NAME,FIRST_NAME_2     LAST_NAME,LAST_NAME_2
CC_CASES    CC_CONTACT      X_OIB,X_MB_OIB  X_JMBG,X_X_JMBG_2   FIRST_NAME                  LAST_NAME
```

I have about 8 different id. I tried to do with a PIVOT function. I also tried with a LISTAGG function, but I can't get the result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    owner,
    table_name,
    listagg(case when attribute_id = 0 then column_name end, ',')
        within group(order by column_name) oib_col,
    listagg(case when attribute_id = 1 then column_name end, ',')
        within group(order by column_name) jmbg_col,
    listagg(case when attribute_id = 2 then column_name end, ',')
        within group(order by column_name) first_name_col,
    listagg(case when attribute_id = 3 then column_name end, ',')
        within group(order by column_name) last_name_col
from mytable
group by owner, table_name
order by owner, table_name
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e377c0a08b80213a1336415886b363a)**:

```
OWNER    | TABLE_NAME | OIB_COL        | JMBG_COL          | FIRST_NAME_COL          | LAST_NAME_COL        
:------- | :--------- | :------------- | :---------------- | :---------------------- | :--------------------
CC_CASES | CC_CONTACT | X_MB_OIB,X_OIB | X_JMBG,X_X_JMBG_2 | FIRST_NAME              | LAST_NAME            
USER     | CC_CASES   | X_OIB,X_OIB_2  | X_JMBG,X_JMBG_2   | FIRST_NAME,FIRST_NAME_2 | LAST_NAME,LAST_NAME_2
```